# Swift 2.0 How to unwrap in check?

Tags: swift

I have found a topic but it seems it's not the same ... 
[Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' Using Parse In Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159412/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped-did-you-mean-to-use-or-u)

i have an error

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) 
    {
            if textField.text.isEmpty || count(textField.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))
    == 0
            {
                textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: Messages.conversationNamePlaceholder.rawValue,
                    attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.54)])
            }
    }
```

Comment: reformat your question. it showing `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

Comment: You need to learn about optional values http://stackoverflow.com/q/24003642/1959140

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' Using Parse In Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159412/value-of-optional-type-string-not-unwrapped-did-you-mean-to-use-or-u)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are trying to apply the method "isEmpty" to an optional-wrapped string "textfield.text".

You should replace your if statement with the following:

```
if textField.text?.isEmpty || count(textField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))
```

text is optional in textfield because a textfield's text can be nil! Watch out for these cases when unwrapping optional objects!

If you want to provide a base case you could to something like this:

```
let text = textfield.text? ?? ""
```

Then you can replace all occurrences of textfield.text with this variable and be sure it will never be nil!

Comment: You should avoid force-unwrapping with `!` as much as possible.

Comment: Agreed! I commented this in the end, but I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Also, take a look at the condition — I think it can be simplified.

Comment: Error because of count

Answer (score 1):

The ! sign should be avoid, therefore I normally go for something like this:

```
if textField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).characters.count > 0 {
    ...
}
```

Using the ! unwraps an optional value, but if the value is nil, a fatal error will crash your app.